# Error handling parsing JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2, alamofire

I'm using `Alamofire` and am parsing the returned JSON into an object as shown below:

```
final class User: NSObject, ResponseObjectSerializable {
    var id: Int
    var facebookUID: String?
    var email: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var phone: String?
    var position: String?
    var timeCreated: CVDate

    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, var representation: AnyObject) {
        if let dataRepresentation = ((representation as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as? [String: AnyObject]) {
            representation = dataRepresentation
        }

        if let id = representation.valueForKeyPath("id") as? Int {
            self.id = id
        } else {
            self.id = 0
        }

        if let facebookUID = representation.valueForKeyPath("facebook_UID") as? String {
            self.facebookUID = facebookUID
        }

        if let email = representation.valueForKeyPath("email") as? String {
            self.email = email
        } else {
            self.email = ""
        }

        if let firstName = representation.valueForKeyPath("first_name") as? String {
            self.firstName = firstName
        } else {
            self.firstName = ""
        }

        if let lastName = representation.valueForKeyPath("last_name") as? String {
            self.lastName = lastName
        } else {
            self.lastName = ""
        }

        if let phone = representation.valueForKeyPath("phone") as? String {
            self.phone = phone
        }

        if let position = representation.valueForKeyPath("position_name") as? String {
            self.position = position
        }

        if let timeCreated = representation.valueForKeyPath("time_created") as? String {
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
            if let date = formatter.dateFromString(timeCreated) {
                self.timeCreated = CVDate(date: date)
            } else {
                self.timeCreated = CVDate(date: NSDate())
            }
        } else {
            self.timeCreated = CVDate(date: NSDate())
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, is this style the best way to decode JSON and set the non-optional instance variables? For example, in this statement:

```
if let id = representation.valueForKeyPath("id") as? Int {
    self.id = id
}
```

I am required by the compiler to add an else clause and set the `id` to something otherwise xCode throws an error saying: `self.id is not initialized at implicitly generated super.init call`.

But at the same time, intializing `self.id` with a value of `0` is wrong and doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But at the same time, intializing self.id with a value of 0 is wrong and doesn't help me at all.

If having a default value for `self.id` feels wrong, then you should make this property an Optional. That way you wouldn't have to add an else clause:

```
final class User: NSObject, ResponseObjectSerializable {
    var id: Int?
    var facebookUID: String?
    var email: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var phone: String?
    var position: String?
    var timeCreated: CVDate

    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, var representation: AnyObject) {
        if let dataRepresentation = ((representation as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as? [String: AnyObject]) {
            representation = dataRepresentation
        }

        if let id = representation.valueForKeyPath("id") as? Int {
            self.id = id
        }

        ...
```

*Update*

You said in the comments:

> I always need to have an id for the user object though.

If you have to have this `id` property then the question is moot, you just have to do

```
let id = representation.valueForKeyPath("id") as! Int
```

and guarantee *earlier* that this value will exist.

Because if your object *needs* an ID, then you can't initialize it anyway *if* this value doesn't exist *and* if you don't want a default value.

Comment: I always need to have an id for the user object though. Is there a way I can throw an error if I'm not supplied with one through the User class or is that a bad practice to do inside of there?

Comment: Well if you have to have this `id` then all this is moot, you just have to do `let id = representation.valueForKeyPath("id") as! Int` and guarantee *earlier* that this value will exist. Because if your object *needs* an ID, then you can't init anyway if this value doesn't exist *and* if you don't want a default value.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's what I'm gonna have to do. I just didn't want the app to crash in case some glitch happened on the backend and I wasn't being supplied an id for whatever reason

Answer (score 1):

You could use ?? to provide default values like this:

```
self.id = (representation.valueForKeyPath("id") as? Int) ?? 0
```

Answer (score 0):

While the `ResponseObjectSerializable` code is a great example from the Alamofire project, it's really a better idea to use a dedicated JSON parsing library that has actual error states. This is far better than using optionals to represent error states, or having to provide a default value for every field just in case the response isn't correctly formed.

Although it has a bit of learning curve, I prefer to use [Argo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo) for my JSON parsing. Once you get the hang of it it makes JSON parsing practically bulletproof. Better yet, it's easy to integrate with Alamofire, especially version 3 that was released today.

Answer (score 0):

To address your concern about not having an ID being an error condition, you could use a failable initializer. I did that in a recent project. Looks something like this:

```
let id: Int!

init? (inputJson: NSDictionary) {

    if let id = inputJson["id"] as? Int {
        self.id = id
    } else {
        // if we are initing from JSON, there MUST be an id
        id = nil
        cry(inputJson) // this logs the error
        return nil
    }
}
```

Of course, this means your code will need to accept that the initialization of your entire object may fail ..